# Can I (& should i) use PHP in django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I wrote a cart application for an event registration in django, and im up to the last part that I cant seems to figure out. I've gotten as far as submitting the cart to paypal for payment but now its time for the IPN and i dont know how to do that. I realized that there are php ipn scripts online that i can just download but cant find that for django. Django-paypal app is confusing the hell out of me so I was wondering. Is it possible for me to just create a django template called ipn.php and have the php paypal ipn script live in that? When paypal goes to it, it will do all of the validation stuff and interact with my database ( same db django app is using , updating paid status). Is this possible? is there another way around this? anyway to make it easier? Thanks.

Comment: No, Django uses **Python**, not PHP. It won't run a PHP script for you.

Comment: Why not ask a question about the Django-Paypal app instead?

Comment: because i wouldnt even know where start and yes ive been trying with the docs, Im new to django and coding in general

Comment: Trying to integrate PHP into a Python app is not going to be the way to solve this then.

Comment: any suggestions then, pointers? resources?

Comment: Sorry, no. I'd point you to Django-Paypal. Perhaps learn Python and Django properly first?

Answer (score 0):

[`django-paypal`](https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal) comes with an IPN callback url prewritten for you. [Step 4 in the readme](https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal/blob/master/README.md) shows you how to hook it up. If in doubt, read the manual.